# Laravel install in localhost

Tags: laravel

I am using windows 8 .I am using XAMPP.I installed XAMPP in `D` drive. My web root path is `D:\php\htdocs`. Location of php.exe file is `D:\php\php`. I would like to install `Composer` first then `Laravel` using composer. Could any one show me the whole process with step by step instruction ??

Comment: There are plenty of guides for this available. Personally I think you should use Laravel Homestead http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

Comment: Thanks @TheShiftExchange. Actually I am facing problem while I am installing `COMPOSER`.Thanks

Comment: Seconding Homestead - it's far and away the easiest way to get Laravel up and running on Windows. Basically, it's a virtual machine running on Linux but you can work directly on the files in Windows (gross oversimplification).

Comment: Yeah, Composer will work fine with Windows, but it's a little bit more involved and everything just works better with Homestead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add Php installation path to Environment Variable.
2. Cd to D:\xampp\php [Php Installation path]
3. Install composer using, `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`
4. Create composer.bat file, using `D:\xampp\php>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat`
5. Check the installation using `composer -V`.
6. If it works fine, install laravel using the following command. `composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp --prefer-dist`

Comment: Thanks @Jeno Karthic for your reply. I used Environment Variable like this `D:\php\php`. I followed your instruction. But my problem is it creates project in `D:\php\php` not in `htdocs`.

Comment: now you need to CD(change directory) to your required folder. (D:\php\htdocs in your case) & Run the composer. It will work fine now.

Comment: Thanks @Jeno Karthic. I tried your instruction but failed. Moreover my pc does not recognize this command.(`composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp --prefer-dist`). I used this command `php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel myapp --prefer-dist`. Thanks

Comment: Have you added the Php installation path(php.exe) to system's environmental variable PATH. Where Composer.phar file is present

Comment: What's happening when you run 'php composer.phar' from php installation location

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and run the Composer Windows Installer from here: https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Go to web root directory `D:\php\htdocs`
3. Run `composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp`, this will install laravel project in `D:\php\htdocs\myapp` directory.