# How to run laravel project on localhost using wamp?

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

I am new in laravel. I have install laravel successfully but now I am unable to serve on localhost. My file path is C:\wamp\www\testproject inside testproject I have laravel directory structure. So, can anyone tell me that how can I serve on localhost. Please help me ?

Thank You

Comment: create virtual host

Comment: what happens when you visit `localhost/laravel/public` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel install in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751546/laravel-install-in-localhost)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, I first installed the composer and installed laravel, then followed this article to create laravel project and run using WAMP Server.
https://medium.com/@essienekanem/how-to-create-you-first-laravel-app-with-wamp-server-and-composer-2bc471274c16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of open CMD
2. CMD -> cd testproject (go to your project directory )[image]
3. CMD -> CD php artisan serve[image]
4. Than run that url http://127.0.0.1:8000 [image]

Complate installation and run : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zq639PQosDU&index=4&list=PLnBvgoOXZNCP2LEKmvu2W-eUkO-DYn0TL

Answer (score 0):

You can serve on your local host by the following command:-
`php artisan serve`
This is the by default artisan command which will serve your application on local host port 8000. This command needs to be passed in cmd after navigating to your laravel root directory.

Another way you can add virtual host on your system configuration and serve your application with virtual domain name also.

Do try any of the above and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In **c://windows/system32/driver/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 www.your-project-name.local
```

In **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin www.your-project-name.local
    DocumentRoot "your project folder path"
    ServerName www.your-project-name.local
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

OR

**php artisan serve** will work fine

Answer (score 0):

open project folder in terminal

run

```
   php artisan serve
```

or

```
   php -s localhost:portnumber -t public
```

Comment: or else just localhost/testproject/public/index.php

Comment: then follow your respective urls but it's not a good practice .kindly use php artisan serve  it has lot of advantages.

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual host that refers to the public path of your laravel project

Or you can use [laragon](https://laragon.org/docs/install.html) as local server just like wamp , it will create auto virtual host for you.

As example, you have projet in the folder

C://laragon/www/projrct1

Then the laragon will create one virtual host for project1

And you can easily run this projects by typing

"project1.dev" in the address bar of your browser

But if you don't want to use laragon as local server you can also create virtual host that can refer to the public folder of your laravel app

You can follow these instructions:

https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/