# Run Laravel project on local setup

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a project which was completed earlier by previous developer team using laravel framework and it is hosted on live.

I have downloaded the source code using FTP 'Filezilla' from the live server and have the full project folder or the hard drive.

Now In order to make changes and understand I want to set it locally.

I want to set it up in local environment where I use WAMP server.

Please suggest me how can I proceed and in which All files I have to make changes.

So please tell me how can I install the same . It will be helpful if step-by step instruction can be provided.

I am new to laravel and wanting to learn the framework. Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 1. changes in .env file if not exists create one in parent level. 2. Make changes regarding environment and database credentials. 3. composer update 4. create vHost 5. add in vHost entry in hosts file 6. restart apache2 7. hit vHost url in browser

Comment: Hi, I suggest you go through the [Laravel installation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation) and try out some of the search results for "How to run Laravel on Wamp", like [this](http://www.darwinbiler.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-wamp-for-beginners/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057738/how-to-run-laravel-project-on-localhost-using-wamp) and [this](https://laravel.io/forum/02-27-2014-install-laravel-on-windows-wamp-server) and then come back to StackOverflow once you have more specific questions.

Comment: I'd start with the Laravel docs, not another developer's code (unless that developer is a prominent one in the Laravel community). I've seen a lot of Laravel apps built in very **non** Laravel ways.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to project folder and install / update the composer.
2. Update the .env file (if it is .env.example then rename it .env file) and add all the required configuration of .env file.
3. Generate the key by `php artisan key:generate` command.
4. Run the commands `composer dumpautoload` (dump-autoload command which won't download anything new, but looks for all of the classes it needs to include again and helps to regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project).
5. `php artisan config:cache` (clear the config cache)
6. Run the command `php artisan serve`. (Start the server).

I hope this will be useful.